# How to re-use fetched data in php

Tags: php, var-dump

I get data from exchanges, but they have a rate limit, means I cannot fetch the data too often. However, during programming I would like to start at the point where I had already the data.
The last line of the fetched code is just a var_dump. How can I store that and start from that point again and again, without fetching new data?

Comment: The thing you are `var_dump`ing is a variable, no? If so can't you just use it like that..

Comment: create new session and save the data in that session, then you can unset it later when you don't need the data anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Encode it as JSON using `json_encode` and store it in a file or database to manipulate later without having to make a new call to the exchange.

Answer (score 0):

`var_dump` is not meant for saving a variable nor for saving state. This function displays structured information about one or more expressions that includes its type and value. [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)

If you need the data to be persistent, Meaning, you will need it for a few weeks,months, year or infinity, you have to encode it in `JSON` and store it somewhere like @jstur said. However, if you are using a relational database like `MySQL/MariaDB`, you can create another table and store it without encoding.

If you will need the data while the user is currently logged-in. Saving it to the `session` is a way to go.But please be aware with php `session`'s limitation and do not overuse it as it may affect your application's performance.